# Join to main thread within a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to make a function that runs inside thread and if..., it will join the main thread. Is there a way to join within the thread that I'm trying to join? Is there even a way to join the main thread?

Code example:

```py
import threading

def function():
    if 1 + 1 == 2:
        # Somehow join the main thraed

threading.Thread(target=function).start()
```

Comment: Can you give a concrete example in code? It seems that what you mean by 'join the main thread' doesn't really correspond with what `.join()` typically does.

Comment: @Grismar Sorry, I didn't realize that's not even what `.join()` does. I edited my question.

Comment: It's still not quite clear what you mean by 'join the main thread'. Do you mean you want to stop running the thread when some condition becomes true? Or do you mean you want to yield to the main thread and return to the thread later after something else has happened? Can you give an example where that actually does something, to show what you're having trouble with?

Comment: @Grismar  I'm using tkinter and can't add widgets within a different thread, I want the thread to join the main thread (it will be considered the main thread) so that now I can edit widgets (since I'm in the main thread). I didn't give an example because this question is not specifically for tkinter, but if you still need one, I'll add code that actually does somthing.

Comment: @DYD This sounds like it might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @AMC I'll ask a different question on only one thing (so it won't be[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) when I could (90 minutes), and I'll delete or edit this one depending on the answer.

Comment: I do think it's an "XY Problem" in that what your problem is sounds like "I need to edit a widget in another / the main thread", while you are asking "how do join another / the main thread". As long as you have the code to do what you want in the thread that owns the widget and you figure out how to signal the code in the other thread to execute that code, your problem would be solved, yes?

Comment: @Grismar The problem has nothing to do with tkinter, I just want a thread to become the main thread (and to do this in that thread).

Comment: Sounds like you already know exactly what you need and how to do it - good luck!

Comment: @Grismar I know what I need to do, but not how.

Comment: _The problem has nothing to do with tkinter, I just want a thread to become the main thread (and to do this in that thread)._ I think you might have missed the point that @Grismar was trying to make. Wanting a thread to become the "main one" is an idea for a solution to the **underlying problem**.

Comment: @AMC Yes I understand, but I need to know how to do that (I don't know how to make a thread to become the main thread). Is this not how I should ask it (from the beginning that was my problem)? How can I find out "how to make a thread become the main one", should I ask a new, more specific question?

Comment: @DYD You say that you understand, yet seem to still be fixated on the exact same thing. You have my apologies if my comment was poorly explained, what I was trying to say is that shouldn’t be asking “how to make a thread become the main one”, forget that idea entirely, and return to the original problem. You wrote _from the beginning that was my problem_, can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @AMC My original problem was, I want to run a thread and in that thread (I said `if`... but that doesn't really matter) it will become the main thread. That was/is my problem. I'm really sorry if I didn't explain it clearly.

Comment: @DYD the unclear thing here is what you mean by "becoming the main thread". What does that achieve? The first thread in the process your script is running in isn't special in many ways, so you would be better off describing what you're trying to achieve, instead of asking for something that's either impossible or pointless.

Comment: @Grismar I need one thread to become another. The first thread is where I created the tkinter object, I need another thread to become that first thread (with the tk object). If it is not possible to make one thread become another, then that's the answer.

Comment: It's not possible to make one thread become another - so if you feel that answers your question, there you go. But I cannot think of anything that would ever require one thread to become another. You may need to get another thread to do something from another thread, that's certainly possible. It's also possible to share data between threads in a thread-safe manner. Between the two, you can solve most if not all problems, so I still think you're asking for a solution that does not exist for a problem that could be solved easily; you're just not sharing the actual problem.

Comment: @Grismar Thanks, that's my answer. The reason I would need to do this is because, in tkinter, you can't update the window from a different thread then the thread the window was made in. I have a code that if I run it in the same thread as the window, the window would freeze, so I need multithreading. I also need to update the window, so I need the other thread to become the main thread (which is impossible).

Comment: To do that, you'd set up communication between the threads, so the main thread can update the window, while the other thread runs the work. That's your solution right there, but it doesn't involve one thread becoming another.

Comment: @Grismar Ok thanks! I should've asked about the other problem, sorry.